# php divide last url from text use regex

Tags: php, regex

I have an regex question. what is the best way to divide last url from text use regex? there always have a link at the end of the my text.

one url in the text.

`$str = 'blah blah blah http://www.google.com.hk';`

I would like use

```
$matches = split("http://", $str);
$matches[0]; //text part
"http://".$matches[1]; //url part
```

Or

```
preg_match_all("/http:\/\/[^ ]+/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches); //url part
preg_replace("/http:\/\/[^ ]+/","", $str);//text part
```

So how about multi urls in the text?

For example:

```
$str = 'blah blah blah http://www.google.com.hk blah blah blah http://cn.yahoo.com';
// text part should be `blah blah blah http://www.google.com.hk blah blah blah`
// last url part should be `http://cn.yahoo.com`
// may be more and more urls in the text `blah blah blah http://www.baidu.com` after `http://cn.yahoo.com`...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regex - You can use [strrpos](http://php.net/strrpos) in conjunction with [substr](http://php.net/substr).

```
$str = 'blah blah blah http://www.google.com.hk blah blah blah http://cn.yahoo.com';
echo substr( $str, 0, strrpos( $str, "http://")) . "\n"; // Text part
echo substr( $str, strrpos( $str, "http://")); // URL
```

**Output:**

```
blah blah blah http://www.google.com.hk blah blah blah 
http://cn.yahoo.com
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6DkjhW)